# Select a option & automatically fill the text field but can not go to the first mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

this is my Jquery & html form code : http://www.mediafire.com/file/ik2735dykdk90io/test3.html (download this)
This code has no errors..this works fine..when I select a option
then its value automatically set to the text box & text box become read only...that's ok..It's my target..But I have little bit problem when I select a option (One,Two or Three).. If  I again select the default value "===select option===" then automatically read only text field is not come normally(means read & write mode)...I want if I select "===select option===" option then text field will be automatically become normal mode....Can any one fix this problem by editing this code...thanxx in advanced.....

Comment: I don't think anyone wants to download any code (not to mention that this question becomes useless for anyone else when the link goes dead). Please create a **minimal** test case demonstrating your problem with http://jsfiddle.net/ and include the code in your post as well. For more info, please see http://www.sscce.org/.

Comment: looks easy to do it..but as Felix mentioned..share jsfiddle link and comment here..we may help..

Comment: i'm sorry I can not post here my code.....That's why I give u a download link....I'm sorry....

Comment: this is jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/dontspeak/2zfdq/

Comment: jsfiddle.net here my code doesnot work..because of my lacking knowledge about  jsfiddle.net....normally code is works fine...

Comment: This is your jsfiddle working version: http://jsfiddle.net/2zfdq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/2zfdq/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#myOption").change(function(){
        var textval = $(":selected",this).val(); 
        $('input[name=student_mark]').val(textval);
        myTestForm.student_mark.disabled=(!textval)?false:true;
    })
});​
```